# Complex number doubt

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

If $|z| = \max \{|z-1|,|z+1|\}$, then:

1. $\left| z + \overline{z} \right| =1/2$
2. $z + \overline{z} =1$
3. $\left| z + \overline{z} \right| =1$
4. $z - \overline{z} = 5$

I am totally confused that how to calculate maximum of $|z-1|$ and $|z+1|$, I think they represent line $x=1$ and $x=-1$ and if so then how to calculate maximum.

Please! Guide me how to proceed.

Comment: Max{a,b}=(1/2)*(a+b+|a-b|), for any real a,b, since |z+1|,|z-1|, real, we can use this!

Comment: Something wrong with the question. I think there is no $z$ with this property. It implies $|z|=|z+1|=|z-1|$ which is impossible.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It implies $|z| = |z+1|$ OR $|z| = |z-1|$.  Not both.  Plenty of numbers where *one* of them is true.

Comment: @fleablood Give me one such number. I did not us your naive argument which only gives OR, I used another argument witch gives AND.

Comment: Instead of arguing $|z|=|z+1|= |z-1|$ which is not in the least bit clear why not argue that if $|z| = |z\pm 1|$ then $|z\pm 1| < |z\mp 1|$ so $|z|= \max(|z+1|,|z-1|)$ is impossible.   If $z = a+bi$ and $|z|=|z\pm 1|$ then $a^2 + b^2 = (a\pm 1)^2 + b^2$ so $a=\mp \frac 12$.  But then $|z\mp 1|=\sqrt{(\mp \frac 12\mp 1)^2 + b^2}>\sqrt{\pm \frac 12} + b^2}$.  So $|z| = |z\pm 1| < |z\mp 1|$ and $|z| = \min(|z+1|, |z-1|)$.  And $|z|=\max(|z+1|,|z-1|)$ is impossible. "I used another argument witch gives AND" instead of saying you gave an argument *give* the argument.

Answer (score 1):

There is no complex number $z$ such that $|z|$ is the maximum of $|z-1|$ and $|z+1|$.

One can say that all four options are vacuously true!

Proof: write $z$ as $\frac {(z-1)+(z+1)} 2$. This gives $|z| \leq \frac {|z-1|+|z+1|} 2 \leq \max \{|z-1|,|z+1|\}=|z|$. Hence equality holds throughout. In particular this implies $|z-1|=|z+1|$ so $z$ must lies in the imaginary axis. But then $z=iy$ for some real number $y$ and the given equation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE. note that $|Z|,|z-1|,|z+1|$ are real numbers, so we can solve the equation, here split in two cases
$$ \max \{|z-1|,|z+1|\}=|z-1| or |z+1|\\
(1):|z| =|z-1|\to put \space z=x+iy\\|x+iy|=|x+iy-1|\\\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\\x^2+y^2=x^2+y^2-2x+1\to x=\frac12\\
(2):|z| =|z+1|\to put \space z=x+iy\\|x+iy|=|x+iy+1|\\\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}\\x^2+y^2=x^2+y^2+2x+1\to x=-\frac12\\$$you can see $Re(z)=\pm \frac 12 \to z=\pm \frac 12 +iy$  now
find $z+\bar{z}=(\pm \frac 12+iy )+(\pm \frac 12 -iy) =\pm1$    it seems $Z+\bar{Z}=1$ but when you put $x=\pm 0.5$ in the equation you will find, the question is wrong

let's see
$$|\pm 0.5 +iy| = \max \{|\pm 0.5 +iy-1|,|\pm 0.5 +iy+1|\}\\
\sqrt{(\pm0.5)^2+y^2}=\max \{\sqrt{(\pm 0.5+1)^2+y^2},\sqrt{(\pm0.5-1)^2+y^2} \}$$ but it is impossible $$\sqrt{(0.5)^2+y^2}<\sqrt{(1.5)^2+y^2}$$

Comment: $\pm \frac1 2 +iy$ does not satisfy the given equation. In fact no complex number does.

Comment: NOte that : $$|x|=max\{x,-x\}$$ out of max function is $|z-1|$ or $|z+1|$   ,but not at the same time

Comment: You need $|z|=|z-1|$ AND $|z+1| \leq |z-1|$ or $|z|=|z+1| AND $|z-1| \leq |z+1|$. I can prove that there is no such number.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy; please put for example $z=-0.5 +2i$ to see $|z+1|\leq |z-1|$  , $$\sqrt{(-.5+1)^2+2^2}\leq \sqrt{(-.5-1)^2+2^2}$$

Comment: But $|z|$ is not equal to $|z-1|$ (the maximum of $|z-1|$ and |z+1|$) in this case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i am not getting the logic behind your disagreement to *khosrotast* answer. Please explain me why you are thinking its wrong. Coz i also thinks that khosrotash's answer seems to be correct and options are also there which matches to his answer

Comment: @ShubhamSagar Did you go through my answer? Unless you give a specific example of a number $z$ which satisfies the hypothesis and also the option given in this answer you cannot say that this answer is correct. Can you give me such a number?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  so, is question is wrong???

Comment: @ShubhamSagar Yes, the question is wrong.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I think twice, I feel the question is wrong now,am  I right ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes, it is wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! For ur answer. 

Comment: $|z|=\min(|z+1|, |z-1|)$ is possible but $|z|=\max(|z+1|, |z-1|)$ is not.  If $z=a+bi;a,b\in \mathbb R$ and $|z|=|z\pm 1|$ then $(a\pm 1)^2+b^2 = a^2 +b^2$ and $a=\mp \frac 12$ and $z = \mp \frac 12 + bi$.  But that mean $z\mp 1=\mp \frac 32 + bi$ and $|z\mp 1|>|z|=|z\pm 1|$.  And thus $|z|=\min(|z+1|,|z-1|)$. and $|z|=\max(|z+1|,|z-1|)$ is impossible.  But it'd be nice if Kavi Ram Murthy gave a reason *why* it is wrong rather than it implies $|z|=|z+1|=|z-1|$. It also implies purple monkeys on mars. Claiming $|z|=|z+1|=|z-1|$ looks like s/he doesn't know what $\max$ means.